# Nim-Lang : How to accept arbitrary number of arguments in a procedure

Tags: nim-lang

Is there a way to accept arbitrary number of arguments with **procedure** in **Nim**?

Example if i want to get sum of multiple arguments, it would look something like this

```
proc sum_all(x,y,z: int): int {.discardable.} = 
    return x+y+z
```

In Python it would look something like this

```
def sum_all(*args):
    return sum(args)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nim has [varargs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-varargs) to accept arbitrary number of arguments

```
proc sum_all(numbers: varargs[int]): int {.discardable.} = 
    for number in items(numbers):
      result += number

echo(sum_all(1,2,3));
```